# Installing Craft 3 RC on MAMP Pro - Pointing to the file directory

Tags: install, mamp

After a successful install I point the (MAMP PRO 4+) Document Root to the Craft `/web` folder, which allows the final setup process. (via www/admin) However pointing at the site root (www) triggers this error; `HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException`

I am missing a final step?

Answer (score 2):

Craft 3 does not come up with templates or default entries like Craft 2 so your `templates` directory is probably empty. As soon as you create some files there and link them to your entries you won't see the error when you enter your home url